# Loading underscore template via ajax loses html, need to escape "<", ">"

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, underscore.js

I'm using ajaxify.js (https://github.com/browserstate/ajaxify/blob/master/ajaxify-html5.js) to load page content. This script by default loads scripts from the page asynchronously as follows:

```
$scripts.each(function(){
    var $script = $(this), 
        scriptText = $script.text(),
        scriptType = $script.attr('type'),
        scriptId = $script.attr('id');

    scriptNode = document.createElement('script');

    if(scriptType) {
        $(scriptNode).attr('type', scriptType);
    }

    if(scriptId) {
        $(scriptNode).attr('id', scriptId);
    }

    scriptNode.appendChild(document.createTextNode(scriptText));
    contentNode.appendChild(scriptNode);
});
```

The issue is that with my underscore template, using `$script.text()` ignores the HTML content of the template completely.

On the other hand, using `$script.html()` escapes the `<` and `>` characters from the template code (underscore's `<%` etc...) and the output ends up looking like:

`&lt;% _.each(things,function(thing,key,list){ %&gt;`

How do I get the script's inner html/text intact so that it functions properly with an AJAX load? Thanks!

The full template script is:

```
    <script type="text/html" id='furniture-template'>
        <div class="accordion collapse">
            <div class="accordion-group">
                <% _.each(things,function(thing,key,list){ %>

                <div class="accordion-heading">
                    <a class="no-ajaxy accordion-toggle ic-minus block collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#things-<%= thing.slug %>">
                        <%= thing.title %>
                    </a>
                </div> <!-- header -->

                <div id="things-<%= thing.slug %>" class="accordion-body collapse">
                    <div class="accordion-inner">
                        <% for(var item in thing.items) { %>
                        <div class="item">
                            <% if( thing.items[item].images == true ) { %>
                                <a class="no-ajaxy" data-target="<%= thing.items[item].slug %>-gal" class="img-link ic-cam fl" title="View an example"></a>
                            <% } %>

                            <a 
                                class="item-add ic-plus" 
                                data-title="<%= thing.items[item].title %>" 
                                data-slug="<%= thing.items[item].slug %>"
                                data-img="<%= thing.items[item].images %>"
                                data-shorthand="<%= thing.items[item].shorthand %>"
                                data-price="<%= thing.items[item].price %>"
                            >
                                <%= thing.items[item].title %>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <% } %>
                    </div> <!-- inner -->
                </div> <!-- accordion-body -->

            <% }); %>
            </div>
        </div>
    </script>
```

Comment: I'm confused, why are you reading the content of one script just to create another script tag? What type of element is `$script`?

Comment: Hey Logan. here's the full ajaxify.js so you can see it in context. https://github.com/browserstate/ajaxify/blob/master/ajaxify-html5.js

Comment: @j-man86, possible to get a reduced test case on jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Curious situation. The simple solution would be to use `.html()` and unescape escaped underscore sequences, which is probably what you want (i.e. you probably don't want to unescape everything):

```
$script.html().replace(/&lt;%/gi, '<%').replace(/%&gt;/gi, '%>')
```

Comment: Thanks Ezekiel. That throws an error in Chrome, though: "syntax error: unexpected token return"

Comment: Strange... It works fine for me. It sounds like there may be some other syntax error in the file when you pasted that in. Can you paste complete snippet that causes error?

Comment: For whatever reason it's working now. I don't know what I did. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Haven't you tryed this :

```
contentNode.innerHTML = scriptnode;
```